# UNNEST not working when trying to unwrap values from array in POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am trying to insert some data into a table as such:

```
filterArr:= ARRAY(SELECT row(f_id, sub_id, item_id,item_code ) FROM 
ToList(p_f_id, p_c_id)); 

INSERT INTO my_table (id, d_id, dc, IE_code)
SELECT 
        p_id AS id,
        fr.d_id AS d_id,
        fr.dc AS dc,
        'I' AS IE_code
From UNNEST(filterArr) fr
ON CONFLICT (id, d_id) DO NOTHING;
```

however when I call this procedure,

I have an error that complains of:

```
NOTICE:  items {"(2981,1,64704240,5055125912306-66233804)","(2981,1,66008001,5033849029197-71818244)","(2981,1,64857780,9780952006237-67074218)","(2981,1,64102887,5032510500997-66410192)","(2981,1,67008012,5060031875409-76016747)","(2981,1,63934027,5032510500959-66410324)","(2981,1,64988254,9780952006220-67074201)","(2981,1,64011641,5032510500942-66410301)","(2981,1,67007174,5060031875393-76016764)","(2981,1,66796500,5053947835261-74769014)"})
INFO:  filterArr{"(,,,)"}

ERROR:  null value in column "d_id" violates not-null constraint


my ToList Method:

    items := array(
        select row(p_f_id, p_f_rec.m_sub_id, d.st_item_id, d.st_item_code)
        from mytable)
```

So the items are indeed coming through in the array, they just dont seem to UNNEST in 'filterArr'

probably being quite blind here but a second pair of eyes will be much appreciate.

as you can see there are no NULL values :

```
NOTICE:  items {"(2981,1,64704240,5055125912306-66233804)","(2981,1,66008001,5033849029197-71818244)","(2981,1,64857780,9780952006237-67074218)","(2981,1,64102887,5032510500997-66410192)","(2981,1,67008012,5060031875409-76016747)","(2981,1,63934027,5032510500959-66410324)","(2981,1,64988254,9780952006220-67074201)","(2981,1,64011641,5032510500942-66410301)","(2981,1,67007174,5060031875393-76016764)","(2981,1,66796500,5053947835261-74769014)"})
```

how ever they do not unnest

```
INFO:  filterArr{"(,,,)"}
```

Comment: Table `fr`  is the `UNNEST` of the array. There are not field names associated with that just the values, so no `fr.d_id AS d_id`.

Comment: hi @AdrianKlaver thanks for you reply, i am not too sure what you mean? can you provide an example?

Comment: Something like:`select t.* from unnest(ARRAY[(20,'fair'::varchar), (30,'poor'::varchar),(40,'great'::varchar)]) as t(id int, cond varchar);                            id | cond  
----+-------
 20 | fair
...` Though I would use  Laurenz Albe's answer as it is the cleaner solution.

Comment: **1).** You haven't included an image in your edit. **2).** When you `UNNEST()` an array of records, the columns don't have names unless you specify them, so there was no column `fr.d_id` to reference. See here as an example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7b58a2c75cf7402de9ec84e3ed8aea86 **3).** Your example call to `ToList()` only specifies two inputs, so it's unclear how you expect the resulting rows in the array to have more than two columns. **4).** I strongly suggest you make an example in dbfiddle, demonstrating Exactly what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

As it is directly related to constraint of a particular field, there are two options:

1. Try changing the constraint of column `d_id` to NULL to accept null values, if at all it solves the problem fully.

OR

2. Fix the `NULL` values in the `UNNEST(filterArr)` table.

Comment: the issue is the unnesting isnt working :) not the null values :D

Comment: its null because it hasnt nested into my array

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert to a array of records and back. Keep it simple:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, d_id, dc, IE_code)
SELECT f_id, sub_id, item_id, item_code
FROM ToList(p_f_id, p_c_id);
```

Comment: thanks but this still provides the same error, d_id is still NULL.

Comment: Then either the function does return NULL values, or the table has a NOT NULL column that you omitted in the `INSERT`.

Comment: so looking at items above there is: there does not seem to be a single NULL value in that list. items is what ToList is returning

nothing is populate in filterArr{"(,,,)"} so items is not unnesting in filterArr. But I cannot workout why

Comment: Then you are missing a NOT NULL column in the INSERT list.

Comment: hello, I have add picture to question, is this what you mean?